# PL/SQL procedure within a package

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I use a stored `PACKAGE` `foo` on the database using PL/SQL?

Say the package contains a `PROCEDURE` `bar`. How can I call it?

Comment: Most answers you will find in documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is called by ..

In SQL*Plus:

```
declare
begin
  foo.bar(par1, par2, par3);
end;
```

From odbc/jdbc you typically use the following SQL:

```
SQL_STRING = "{ call foo.bar(?, ?, ?) }"
```

Comment: or use execute(exec) call:  SQL>exec foo.bar(p1,p2,p3);